# Problem on cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I'm trying to prove the following:

Show that complex conjugation restricts to the automorphism $\sigma_{-1} \in \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) / \mathbb{Q})$ of the cyclotomic field of nth roots of unity. Show that the field $K^+=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})$ is the subfield of real elements in $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, called the maximal real subfield of K.

I really have no clue how to do this one and been stuck for a while, thanks in advance!

Comment: The first part follows at once from the observation that if $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$ , then $\;|z|=1\iff \overline z=z^{-1}\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio At first the real subfield is generated by all the $\zeta_n^m+\zeta_n^{-m}$ only then show $[Q(\zeta_n):Q(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})] = 2$

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure why you address me. What I meant with my above comment is that the first part of the question follows at once from what I wrote...

Comment: Related to @reuns' comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448011/maximal-real-subfield-of-a-number-field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read my comment above, and now:

$$\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}=\zeta_n+\overline{\zeta_n}=2\text{ Re }\zeta_n=2\cos\frac{2\pi}n$$

and you get the extension is real. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I see the idea but can you elaborate a bit further? thanks!